# Setting up a background color on div (bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]I am pretty new to the coding, but even I know how to set up a background color in the `div`, but for some reason, I cant do it with the following piece of code:

```
<div class="text-center">
    <h1>Welcome to Ika Ika Surf Camp Tenerife.</h1>
    <h4>A NEW CONCEPT OF SURF CAMP AND SURF SCHOOL IN THE CENTER OF PLAYA DE LAS AMERICAS, TENERIFE</h4>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <h3>Surf School</h3> <img alt="surf-school" src="img/ika-ika-guias-surf.jpg">
        <p>Our surf lessons are taught by our fully qualified instructors with extensive surfing experience.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <h3>Surf Guides</h3> <img alt="surf-guides" src="img/ikaika-surf-school-tenerife.jpg">
        <p>The surf camp is located in the center of Playa de las Americas, 50m of the best waves of the island.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <h3>Surf School</h3> <img alt="activities" src="img/tenerife-actividades-skate.jpg">
        <p>Ika Ika Surf camp is a 360º Sport center with Skate, Long Skate, Scuba, Yoga Surf, Pilates and Surf workout.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

So in css, if I set up the bellow code, it only affects `h1` and `h4` for some reason

```
div.text-center {
  background-color: 
}
```

Although if I remove the class of .text-center from the parent `div`, it affects all child `div`'s

Hope somebody can explain me why. I guess it is something to do with bootstrap - this is first time I try to code using it.

Comment: Are you not missing actual color after colon in "background-color:"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1) The parent block has lost its floating children

On the wide screen Bootstrap's columns become floating. Because of this the parent block decides that it has two headers only. And its height becomes less.

This problem has two solutions:

#### 1.1) Overflow

You can set the `overflow` property on the `.text-center` class to `hidden`. This property causes the parent block to take the dimensions considering its floating children.

```css
.text-center {
  background: #f99;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="text-center">
  <h1>Welcome to Ika Ika Surf Camp Tenerife.</h1>
  <h4>A NEW CONCEPT OF SURF CAMP AND SURF SCHOOL IN THE CENTER OF PLAYA DE LAS AMERICAS, TENERIFE</h4>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <h3>Surf School</h3> 
    <img alt="surf-school" src="img/ika-ika-guias-surf.jpg">
    <p>Our surf lessons are taught by our fully qualified instructors with extensive surfing experience.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <h3>Surf Guides</h3> 
    <img alt="surf-guides" src="img/ikaika-surf-school-tenerife.jpg">
    <p>The surf camp is located in the center of Playa de las Americas, 50m of the best waves of the island.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <h3>Surf School</h3> 
    <img alt="activities" src="img/tenerife-actividades-skate.jpg">
    <p>Ika Ika Surf camp is a 360ยบ Sport center with Skate, Long Skate, Scuba, Yoga Surf, Pilates and Surf workout.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### 1.2) Clearfix

Bootstrap rows use this method. You can see it in the [bootstrap.css](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css):

```
.row:before,
.row:after {
  display: table;
  content: " ";
}
.row:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

So you have to wrap your columns into the block with the `.row` class:

```css
.text-center {
  background: #f99;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="text-center">
  <h1>Welcome to Ika Ika Surf Camp Tenerife.</h1>
  <h4>A NEW CONCEPT OF SURF CAMP AND SURF SCHOOL IN THE CENTER OF PLAYA DE LAS AMERICAS, TENERIFE</h4>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <h3>Surf School</h3> 
      <img alt="surf-school" src="img/ika-ika-guias-surf.jpg">
      <p>Our surf lessons are taught by our fully qualified instructors with extensive surfing experience.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <h3>Surf Guides</h3> 
      <img alt="surf-guides" src="img/ikaika-surf-school-tenerife.jpg">
      <p>The surf camp is located in the center of Playa de las Americas, 50m of the best waves of the island.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <h3>Surf School</h3> 
      <img alt="activities" src="img/tenerife-actividades-skate.jpg">
      <p>Ika Ika Surf camp is a 360ยบ Sport center with Skate, Long Skate, Scuba, Yoga Surf, Pilates and Surf workout.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### 2) Container > Row > Column

Bootstrap's [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro) involves a hierarchy of blocks. The container contains rows and rows contain columns:

> - Rows must be placed within a `.container` (fixed-width) or `.container-fluid` (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.
> - Use rows to create horizontal groups of columns.
> - Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be immediate children of rows.

Moreover, the `.row` class has negative margins. If you do not put it into the container, then the horizontal scroll bar will appear on your page.

### 3) Don't change the `.text-center` class

It's one of Bootstrap's [alignment classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment).

You can define your own class for your purposes. Just as I have defined the `.my-background`  class in the code below.

Please check the result. Is it what you want to achieve?

```css
.my-background {
  background: #f99;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container my-background text-center">
  <h1>Welcome to Ika Ika Surf Camp Tenerife.</h1>
  <h4>A NEW CONCEPT OF SURF CAMP AND SURF SCHOOL IN THE CENTER OF PLAYA DE LAS AMERICAS, TENERIFE</h4>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <h3>Surf School</h3> 
      <img alt="surf-school" src="img/ika-ika-guias-surf.jpg">
      <p>Our surf lessons are taught by our fully qualified instructors with extensive surfing experience.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <h3>Surf Guides</h3> 
      <img alt="surf-guides" src="img/ikaika-surf-school-tenerife.jpg">
      <p>The surf camp is located in the center of Playa de las Americas, 50m of the best waves of the island.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <h3>Surf School</h3> 
      <img alt="activities" src="img/tenerife-actividades-skate.jpg">
      <p>Ika Ika Surf camp is a 360º Sport center with Skate, Long Skate, Scuba, Yoga Surf, Pilates and Surf workout.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one out

```
div.text-center {
background-color: #000000;
}
```

Try another work around to find out conflict

```
<div style="background-color: #000000; color: #ffffff;">
```

I have used HTML color codes called 'Hex Color', or you can simply use like white, black. Make sure if you adding color code then should use # before the code. You can try http://htmlcolorcodes.com/ to find color codes

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it only affects the h1 and h2 for some reason, I will attach the screenshot in a moment

Comment: I attached the file, as you see, it only affects first two element, I have no idea why. i used red as background color

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your code.

You have not used `<div class="row">` while using Bootstrap Grids. That's why the background color only effects the `H1` and `h4` tags.

Try the below code:

```css
div.text-center {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-center">
    <h1>Welcome to Ika Ika Surf Camp Tenerife.</h1>
    <h4>A NEW CONCEPT OF SURF CAMP AND SURF SCHOOL IN THE CENTER OF PLAYA DE LAS AMERICAS, TENERIFE</h4>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <h3>Surf School</h3> <img alt="surf-school" src="img/ika-ika-guias-surf.jpg">
        <p>Our surf lessons are taught by our fully qualified instructors with extensive surfing experience.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <h3>Surf Guides</h3> <img alt="surf-guides" src="img/ikaika-surf-school-tenerife.jpg">
        <p>The surf camp is located in the center of Playa de las Americas, 50m of the best waves of the island.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <h3>Surf School</h3> <img alt="activities" src="img/tenerife-actividades-skate.jpg">
        <p>Ika Ika Surf camp is a 360º Sport center with Skate, Long Skate, Scuba, Yoga Surf, Pilates and Surf workout.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the screenshot of the page after adding `<div class="row">`

[image]

Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need an .row class for your layout

```
<div class="colored-bg row text-center">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <h1>...</h1>
    <h4>...</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
      ...
  </div>
</div>
```

And add css of your choice to colored-bg class

```
.colored-bg{
  background-color: tomato;
}
```